# In Haskell, how do I get an average float from a list of integers?

Tags: haskell

I have written a simple function that displays: Name of place, Degrees North, Degrees East, and a list of rainfall numbers.

How do I get an average rainfall specific to a place? For example in my code, how do I get an average rainfall for London?

Sorry if my code is not the best, I'm just learning Haskell.

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List
type Place = (String, Float, Float, [Int])

testData :: [Place]
testData = [("London", 51.5, -0.1, [0, 0, 5, 8, 8, 0, 0]),
            ("Cardiff", 51.5, -3.2, [12, 8, 15, 0, 0, 0, 2]),
            ("Norwich", 52.6, 1.3, [0, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3])]

rainLevels :: [Place] -> Float 
rainLevels level (_, _, _, numbers) = sum numbers / 7
```

Answer (score 2):

To find the average rainfall for "London", you need to first find the record for "London" in your list, then average its rainfall numbers.

`getAvgRainLevel` consumes a name of a specific city: `name`, and a list of records: `xs`; it finds the record of that city by its `name`, then calculates the average rainfall level for that city.

```
getAvgRainLevel name xs = fmap avg $ lookup name (sanitize xs)
  where
    sanitize = fmap (\(city, _, _, rainLevels) -> (city, rainLevels))
    avg = (/) <$> sum <*>  fromIntegral . length
```

Comment: will it be called by typing -  getAvgRainLevel london ?

Comment: getAvgRainLevel "London" testData

Answer (score 1):

If you want to divide `Int`s in Haskell, you *first* have to convert them to `Float`s. This avoids the problems you get with division in other statically typed languages like C, where `5/2` is `2`.

So, how do you convert an `Int` to a `Float`? There are a number of functions for doing this, but the most paradigmatic choice is `fromIntegral`:

```
fromIntegral :: (Num b, Integral a) => a -> b
```

This will convert any Integral type to any Numeric type. Thus if you need to convert a `[Int]` to a `[Float]`:

```
fmap fromIntegral :: (Functor f, Num b, Integral a) => f a -> f b
```

There are another couple problems. Your code will not compile as-is. You have declared your function `rainLevels` to only take one argument, but you pattern match on two arguments when you define it. As currently defined, the actual type of `rainLevels` is:

```
rainLevels :: (Frac e) => a -> (b, c, d, [e]) -> e
```

`Place` matches `(b, c, d, [e])`, but not with the constraint `(Frac e)`, which is what `fromIntegral` will solve, but you'll still be left with the issue that `[Place]` will not pattern match on `(_, _, _, numbers)`. Since my mind-reading skills have sadly lapsed, I leave it to you to work out whether `rainLevels` is meant to take one `Place` or a list of them, but either way, you need to make the signature match the definition.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the explanation of Andrew Ray, I thought it might be helpful to provide an working example in code:

```
module Lib
    ( avgRainLevel
    , rainLevels
    , testData
    ) where

import Data.Char
import Data.List
type Place = (String, Float, Float, [Int])

testData :: [Place]
testData = [("London", 51.5, -0.1, [0, 0, 5, 8, 8, 0, 0]),
            ("Cardiff", 51.5, -3.2, [12, 8, 15, 0, 0, 0, 2]),
            ("Norwich", 52.6, 1.3, [0, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3])]

findPlace :: [Place] -> String -> Place
findPlace placeList place = head . filter isPlace $ placeList
  where isPlace (name, _, _, _) = name == place

getLevel :: Place -> [Int]
getLevel (_, _, _, levels) = levels

rainLevels :: [Place] -> String -> [Int]
rainLevels placeList place = getLevel $ findPlace placeList place

average :: [Int] -> Float
average ints = fromIntegral levelSum / fromIntegral count
  where levelSum = sum ints
        count = length ints

avgRainLevel :: [Place] -> String -> Float
avgRainLevel placeList place = average $ rainLevels placeList place
```

I was a bit unsure what the actual value you want to get. From the name `rainLevels` I concluded that you want the list of rain levels, so I adapted the type to `[Int]`. Because you don't just provide the list of places, but also the actual place you want to query, I had to add another parameter which added a `-> String` to the type declaration of the function.

Based on the function, I did another function `avgRainLevel` that calculates the average of the values in the list of type `[Int]`.

The code will work like documented with these tests:

```
import Lib (rainLevels, avgRainLevel, testData)
import Test.Hspec (Spec, it, shouldBe)
import Test.Hspec.Runner (configFastFail, defaultConfig, hspecWith)

main :: IO ()
main = hspecWith defaultConfig {configFastFail = True} specs

specs :: Spec
specs = do

  it "can read the list of levels" $ do
    let levels = rainLevels testData "London"
    levels `shouldBe` [0, 0, 5, 8, 8, 0, 0]

  it "can calculate the average rain level" $ do
    let avg = avgRainLevel testData "Norwich"
    avg `shouldBe` 2
```

Please note, that actually you shouldn't return `[Int]` or `Float` from any of these two functions. The code as it is will panic when you query for a place, that is not present in the list of places. You should better return `Maybe [Int]` and `Maybe Float`. In that case you can return `Nothing` when you have no information about a given place available.