# Haskell keeps giving me type errors

Tags: haskell

Don't know what I'm doing wrong

```
type Name = String
type Location = (Float,Float)
type RainfallFigures = [Int]
type Place = (Name,Location,RainfallFigures)

rtnClosestDryPlace :: (Location -> Int -> [Place] -> [(Name,Float)]) -> (Name,Float)
rtnClosestDryPlace p1 n ((a,p2,c):xs) = rtnLowestDistance (distanceList p1 (rtnFullDryPlaces ((a,p2,c):xs) n))

    Couldn't match expected type ‘(Name, Float)’
                      with actual type ‘Int
                    -> [(Name, Location, RainfallFigures)] -> (Name, Float)’
        • The equation(s) for ‘rtnClosestDryPlace’ have three arguments,
          but its type ‘(Location -> Int -> [Place] -> [(Name, Float)])
                        -> (Name, Float)’
          has only one
    rtnClosestDryPlace p1 n ((a,p2,c):xs) = rtnLowestDistance (distanceList p1 (rtnFullDryPlaces ((a,p2,c):xs) n))
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^



    template.hs:90:73: error:
        • Couldn't match expected type ‘(Float, Float)’
                      with actual type ‘Location -> Int -> [Place] -> [(Name, Float)]’
        • Probable cause: ‘p1’ is applied to too few arguments
          In the first argument of ‘distanceList’, namely ‘p1’
          In the first argument of ‘rtnLowestDistance’, namely
            ‘(distanceList p1 (rtnFullDryPlaces ((a, p2, c) : xs) n))’
          In the expression:
            rtnLowestDistance
              (distanceList p1 (rtnFullDryPlaces ((a, p2, c) : xs) n))
       |
    90 | rtnClosestDryPlace p1 n ((a,p2,c):xs) = rtnLowestDistance (distanceList p1 (rtnFullDryPlaces ((a,p2,c):xs) n))
       |          ^^
```

Location, Int, [place] all get sent to a function which returns [(Name, Float)], which in turn gets sent to a function which returns (Name,Float) I don't know why this program can't run. Why can it not match the types

Edit: After rewriting the function I’ve managed to correctly write it down with no matching errors

Comment: What does `rtn` stand for? Why is the function not just called `closestDryPlace`?

Comment: rtn stands for return

Comment: All functions return something; you don't need to waste space in the name to emphasize that.

Comment: Which homework are we solving here? The problem that is worked on seems to be very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61365035/in-haskell-how-do-i-get-an-average-float-from-a-list-of-integers

Comment: You’re not solving anything. After I’ve sorted out my type errors I’m good to go. Still don’t know why Haskells complaining.

Comment: Can I just write my functions in the form x y z q without any brackets?

Comment: My function now works after I re-wrote it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your type is wrong:

```
rtnClosestDryPlace :: (Location -> Int -> [Place] -> [(Name,Float)]) -> (Name,Float)
```

means that `rtnClosestDryPlace` is a function whose input argument has type

```
(Location -> Int -> [Place] -> [(Name,Float)])
```

and whose output argument has type

```
(Name,Float)
```

So, that type promises that, given a 3-arguments function, the code below is able to return a pair. That's not what you want.

I guess you actually want something like

```
rtnClosestDryPlace :: Location -> Int -> [Place] -> [(Name,Float)]
```

Comment: I want Location, int and [Place] to be sent to my [(Name,Float)] function, then for that to be finally sent to the function which returns (Name, Float) so I assume the correct type definition would be: rtnClosestDryPlace :: (Location -> Int -> [Place]) -> [(Name,Float)] -> (Name,Float)

Comment: @jamie That could be correct, I guess. That is the type of a 2-arguments function: it takes as input a function and a list-of-pairs, and returns a single pair. Try then fixing your function code to follow that type: right now it uses 3 arguments instead of 2.